# What is NSISEngine?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm going through my app and I've noticed that when I load certain (4 out of 112 to be exact) objects and load it into a `ViewController` with 4 `UIStackView`s all written with code (i.e no xib) there is a noticeable lag when loading, and specifically when loading the `UIStackView`s. I ran a performance trace and notice the only difference between the views that load quickly and the ones that lag is `NSISEngine` methods being called taking about 6x longer (specifically `[NSISEngine Optimize]`). Does anyone know why this would only pop up for < 5% of cases?

- Amount of data for each object doesn't matter since there are large objects that don't have this problem.
- I am using custom `UIStackView`s that are expandable when tapped and this is the code I'm using:

  ```
   func toggle() {
      // only toggle if there's a subView
      guard subView != nil else {
          return
      }
      let rotation = isExpanded ? 0 : π / 2
      isExpanded = !isExpanded
      setSpacing(for: self) // this takes 1e-6s 
      t1 = Date()
      UIView.animate(withDuration: kExpansionTime, animations: {
          self.arrowView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotation)
          self.subView?.isHidden = !self.isExpanded
          self.layoutIfNeeded() // no change if this is removed.
      }) {_ in
          t2 = Date()
          print(t2.timeIntervalSince(t1)) // prints ~1s on bad cases and 1e-3 normally
      }
  }
  ```

**Edit**: This doesn't happen on iOS 10, only in iOS 9 (could this be a bug)?

Comment: It's the layout constraint solver.

Comment: Hmm so I should have a closer look at the constraints I'm creating in my `StackView`s I guess ?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone was curious as to what was causing they optimization issue, I was using a `UILabel`  with `numberOfLines = 0`. The `Label` was in a `StackView` that had the following properties

```
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.alignment = .center
stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
```

I switched the `numberOfLines = 1` and it fixed it.